# How do I enumerate rows returned in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql

Similar to how Python's `enumerate()` works, I'd like to assign each row returned a unique increasing integer.  (Not the row id, but rather the row number in the results!)

i.e.,

```
for p in models.People.objects.all().values('N', 'name'):
   print p['N'], p['name']
```

with output of...

```
0 Mary
1 John
2 Nikita
3 Fred
```

In this particular case, I want to do this on the SQL backend and not simply wrap `enumerate()` around the query results.

I would also not expect the enumerations to be stable across queries where the data has changed.

Comment: Is there behavior you want other than calling `enumerate` on the queryset? Querysets are iterable, so you can just do that if it suits your needs. Or are you looking for an ID that's stable between queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `annotate` in Django 1.x:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL                                 

qry = models.People.objects.all().\
    annotate(N=RawSQL('row_number() over ()', [])).\
    values('N', 'name')
for p in qry:
    print p['N'], p['name']
```

In Django 2.0 this can be done with a [`Window`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Window) expression using [`RowNumber`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#rownumber).